# Is there better way to check value changed in sequence?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a **list** like below:

```
list = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
```

And, I want to count the number of the first value (in case above, 'A') consecutively before the other values ('B') come.

So I wrote a code like:

```
history = list[0]
number_A = 0
number_B = 0
for i in list:
    if history != i:
        break

    if i == 'A':
        number_A += 1
        history = 'A'
    else:
        number_B += 1
        history = 'B'
```

However, I think this is very untidy.
Is there any  more simple way to do this process?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Can there be more values or just A and B?

Comment: If `'A'` and `'B'` are the only possible values, then `.index('B')` is the answer.  This returns the list position of the first `'B'`, and therefore all preceding characters will be consecutive `'A'`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with the default key function, you can count the number of items in the first grouper:

```
from itertools import groupby

def count_first(lst):
    if not lst:
        return 0
    _, grouper = next(groupby(lst))
    return sum(1 for _ in grouper)

print(count_first(['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']))  
# 2
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason for the "else" clause, you are not going to count 'B's since you are going to break before you get there.

```
lst = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']

count = 0

for i in lst:
    if i != lst[0]:
        break
    count += 1

print("list starts with %d of %s's" % (count, lst[0]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use takewhile:

```
from itertools import takewhile

my_list = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']

res = takewhile(lambda x: x == my_list[0], my_list)
print(len(list(res)))
```

> OUT: 2

Comment: If you want it for each element in your list, wrap it in a for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

I renamed your list to `lst` in order to not override the builtin name `list`.

```
>>> lst = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
>>> string = ''.join(lst)
>>> len(string) - len(string.lstrip('A'))
2
```